# Find out if $A^TA+I$ is a positive definite matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, positive-definite

If we have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R^{mxn}}$ and $I$ as the identity matrix of $n \times  n$, with linearly independent columns, can we say that $A^TA+I$ is positive definite? I took an example case where $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&4\\5&6\end{pmatrix}$$ which means that $$A^TA+I= \begin{pmatrix}23&28\\49&64\end{pmatrix}$$
but then I get that 
$$\begin{vmatrix}23&28\\49&64\end{vmatrix} < 0$$ therefore its not positive definite. Is this correct?

Comment: Note that $A^TA + I$ is supposed to be a symmetric matrix, but your calculated result is not symmetric. So something has gone wrong.

Comment: I second @Arthur's point. I recommend you edit in your calculation of $A^TA$ so we can see how you mishandled it; then we can help with that. (Actually, you should probably also show how you calculated the determinant, as you got the sign wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

1. $\quad \begin{vmatrix}23&28\\49&64\end{vmatrix} =100 >0.$
2. We have $x^TA^TAx \ge 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n.$ This gives, with $B:=A^TA+I:$

$$x^TBx >0$$

for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$ with $x \ne 0.$ Hence $B$ is positive definite.

Comment: Would it work the same way if you had $B:=A^TA-I$ if you're trying to find if $A^TA-I$ is positive definite?

Comment: No. Take, for example $A=I$. Then $B=0.$